# React native google sign in not working in release version on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, google-signin

I have a react native expo project with react-native-google-signin module (and also with other modules) and I setup the way the documentations described. I made an OAuth client on google console and copied the SHA1 from the output of this command: `keytool -list -v -keystore app/debug.keystore`. I found this command from [this](https://peerlist.io/blog/engineering/implementing-google-signin-in-react-native) article.

The app works when I run in development mode using my phone. I build the release using eas and it's run perfectly on my phone but when I sent the release apk to my friend the google sign in appeared but not loged in even when he selected his own google account the sign in window just closed but no error appeared.

I don't know what could be the problem because I followed the guide from [here](https://react-native-google-signin.github.io/docs/setting-up/expo).

I also setup the firebase and added the google-services.json but it dind't helped.

EDIT: I found out that when I run `gradlew signingReport` it lists the installed npm packages without hash and the `Store` is `D:\AndroidSDK\.android\debug.keystore`. I generated a key pair using keytool but now the hash is different that I have in the `app/debug.keystore`. I think this could be the problem. How can I fix this?